# multiplication of all integers between two given variables using recursion

Tags: loops, recursion, integer, multiplication

Yes this is homework. I am not asking for any easy answers, just help moving in the right direction. here is the assignment: "Create a function that receives two numbers: a and b.  The function calculates and returns the multiplication of all the numbers between a and b. Create three versions of this function."
I created the function using a for loop and a while loop, but I am at a loss how to use recursion- the final part of the assignment.

Answer (score 3):

Kudos for admitting this is a homework question.  As such, while I won't give you the answer, I will give you a few pointers towards it.

When writing a recursive function, there are two key things to consider:

1. What stops the recursion, and
2. What happens until the recursion stops

In your case, where you have to calculate the product of a list of numbers, this works out as:

1. What should the function do when there is only 1 item in the list? (ie: when a and b are the same)
2. How can I multiply one element by the product of the rest of the list?

For extra credit, look up tail recursion and understand why it can help keep your memory usage down.

Does that give you enough of a start?

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple instance of [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) — you start with one problem and attempt to resolve it by breaking it into problems that are easier to solve and combining the results.

You can then usually attack these problems by working backwards: what's the most trivial case, that you could answer immediately? What would you do if the problem were a notch harder than that?

As you've explicitly been told to find a recursive solution, you can assume that you're looking for a method that can either directly return a result or else must call itself with modified parameters, and do something with that result to get its own.

Failing that, given that the question is slightly artificial, consider looking up how you could literally just implement a for loop using a recursive structure, then directly adapt your existing for loop. No great thought about the nature of breaking problems down, just looking at how to express your existing solution in a different way.

Answer (score -1):

```
function recursiveMultiplication(num1, num2) {
    if (num2 == num1) {
        return num2;
    }

    return num2 * recursiveMultiplication(num1, num2 - 1);
}
console.log(recursiveMultiplication(5, 8));
```

Comment: To be very honest i have learned recursion today. All you need is dedication and hard work. but don't do everything on your own learn how other people code this way you will divide your problems in even more simpler forms :D